# Convert byte[,] to byte[]

Tags: .net, image-processing

Does anyone know of an efficient way to flatten a 2d array (non-jagged) in C# to a 1d and back again. I know in the back end C# must hold onto it as a 1d array I would just like to get a handle on the back end 1d array if at all possible.

The reason why I would like to do this is because I would like to be able to in managed code have it as a 2d, at times I would like to hand it off as a 1d to unmanaged dll imported code (optimized assembly in digital image processing is a good example).

Comment: "I know in the back end C# must hold onto it as a 1d array" What makes you think that? It doesn't have to be the case at all.

Comment: @Jason: Actually, the following line in the specification seems to suggest that you _can_ assume that the underlying representation is a linear array. From §18.6: "Given the way in which arrays are stored, we can treat an array of any dimension as though it were linear." However, do note that this did not need to be the case but it is very nice that it is true.

Comment: @Jason: Haha, did you just correct yourself?

Comment: @Dan Tao: Let's just think of it as an elaboration. :-)

Comment: @Jason: Sure... or a sudden bout of dissociative identity disorder ;)

Comment: @Dan Tao: I contain multitudes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get a managed `byte[]` array from a `byte[,]` without copying it out (not that I know of, anyway).

If you're comfortable with `unsafe` code you can fix a `byte*` on the array and I believe that should work:

```
fixed (byte* ptr = array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        byte b = ptr[i];
        // Do whatever you need.
    }
}
```

Comment: @dko: It does work. See my comment to Jon Skeet's answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674394/convert-byte-to-byte/4674427#4674427.

Comment: @Jason Do you know if it is stored in row major or column major order? AKA byte[5,5] temp, would indexing temp[0,3] be the 3rd byte or the 15th byte?

Comment: @dko: It's row-major order. From the specification: "For multi-dimensional arrays, array elements are stored such that the indices of the rightmost dimension are increased first, then the next left dimension, and so on to the left." So, `temp[0, 3]` is the FOURTH byte (you were off by one in asking if it's the third).

Comment: @dko: I'm not surprised that it works - but I'd personally expect BlockCopy to be faster.

Comment: @Jon Skeet If this works I won't need to copy it, so this would be the fasts way. @Jason oops you're right 4th byte my bad *head slap*

Comment: @Jason Also where are you getting this specification?

Comment: @dko: I don't understand you - do you not actually need a `byte[]` after all?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I think he's saying he'll just use a unsafe pointer to get at what he needs and pass it to some unmanaged DLL.

Comment: @dko: Google "ECMA 334" or look in `c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\Specifications\1033\CSharp Language Specification.doc` or the analogous directory depending on where you installed Visual Studio and what version you have.

Comment: @Jon: I think by `byte[]` the OP originally just meant "a linearly arranged sequence of bytes," not "a CLR `byte[]` array"; it doesn't sound to me like he actually needs to *copy* the bytes. Of course how he gets this `byte*` off to the unmanaged DLL is unknown to me. Sounds like he has his ways. (@dko: I apologize if you're a woman and I just called you "he" like five times.)

Comment: @Dan Tao nope your fine I'm a guy. Thanks for all the answers, in unmanaged c dll's typically arrays are passed as (char * arr, int length) So by the sounds of it I can pass the to this unmanaged method call byte*, width * height)

Answer (score 11):

Well, the object itself isn't a `byte[]`, even though it's got the data itself in one contiguous block of memory. Don't forget that an array knows its ranks and lengths etc as well.

However, you can use [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx) to copy the array quickly. For example:

```
byte[,] source = new byte[5,5];
byte[] dest = new byte[source.Length];
Buffer.BlockCopy(source, 0, dest, 0, source.Length);
```

Note that the final argument is the number of *bytes*, not the number of array elements.

Comment: Relevant line from specification from §18.6: "Given the way in which arrays are stored, we can treat an array of any dimension as though it were linear." In particular, it's possible to say `byte[] destination = new byte[source.Length]; unsafe { fixed (byte *p = source) { for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++) { destination[i] = p[i]; } } }` and the code will work as expected.

Comment: Also, it's obviously better to say `byte[] dest = new byte[source.Length];` and `Buffer.BlockCopy(source, 0, dest, 0, source.Length * sizeof(byte));`

Comment: @Jason: Yes, that's true - although I wouldn't bother with the `sizeof(byte)`... maybe for anything less trivial though :)

Comment: I did it merely to draw attention to the fact that the last parameter to `Buffer.BlockCopy` is the number of __bytes__ to copy, not the number of __elements__.

Comment: @Jason: Yup, that makes sense. I'll edit to draw attention to that, but not in the code.

Answer (score 3):

To go from a 2D index to 1D index:

```
int i = y * width + x;
```

And back:

```
int x = i % width;
int y = i / width;
```

Then the simplest is to just iterate over your array, copying the values one by one.

Comment: That's far from the most *efficient* way to copy the data though.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Actually I haven't seen the Buffer.BlockCopy, so I haven't measured the performance of it. I'll take your word for it that it's faster though. :) Would be interesting to see some performance numbers to see what the difference is. I'll remember that one as this question comes up a lot (I'm pretty sure that this question is in fact a duplicate, just can't find another one right now that's a good match).

Comment: Yes this is far from what I was referring to as an efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myFlattenedByteArray = my2DByteArray.SelectMany(b=>b).ToArray();
```

This will return each element of each subarray of the 2D byte array in subarray-element order: myFlattenedByteArray[1] == my2DByteArray[0][1]. There are probably more performant or efficient solutions (especially the slupring of the Enumerable produced by SelectMany into its own Array) but it's a one-liner.